# How can I see switch media dialog without changing sound volume?

Tags: windows-10, audio

On my new Dell XPS (but as far as I understand it's a Windows 10 feature) each time I'm changing the volume I see following dialog which actually proved to be very convenient way to switch between your media sources.

My question would be - how can I see this dialog without changing the volume?

[image]